# Combine two x-y plots using SwiftUI and the Charts Library

Tags: swiftui, ios-charts

I am working with SwiftUI and the Charts Library (ie import Charts)

All OK with producing a singe line.
However I want to plot 2 separate lines on the chart

But cannot work out how to do this

I call the struct with the following line:

```
myLineChartSwiftUI(myXminny: self.$myXminny, myXmaxy: self.$myXmaxy)
```

I have added the 2nd line setup (ie dataPoints2, set2, color2 etc )

How the hell do I combine the 2 lines to return then for the plot?

Help would be very much appreciated

My first swiftUI and 1st Charts program:

```
struct myLineChartSwiftUI : UIViewRepresentable
{
    @Binding var myXminny : Double
    @Binding var myXmaxy  : Double

    let lineChart = LineChartView()

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<myLineChartSwiftUI>) -> LineChartView {
        setUpChart()
        return lineChart
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: LineChartView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<myLineChartSwiftUI>) {

    }

    func setUpChart() {
        
        let dataSets = [getLineChartDataSet()]
        let data = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
        lineChart.data = data
    }

    func getChartDataPoints(sessions: [Double], accuracy: [Double]) -> [ChartDataEntry] {
        var dataPoints: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        for count in (0..<sessions.count) {
            dataPoints.append(ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(sessions[count]), y: accuracy[count]))
        }
        return dataPoints
    }

    func getLineChartDataSet() -> LineChartDataSet {

        let dataPoints = getChartDataPoints(sessions: [myXminny,myXmaxy], accuracy: [myXminny,myXmaxy]) 
        let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataPoints, label: "DataSet")
        set.lineWidth = 2
        set.drawValuesEnabled = false
        set.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        //set.circleRadius = 4
        let color = ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()[4]
        set.setColor(color)

        let dataPoints2 = getChartDataPoints(sessions: [myXminny/2,myXmaxy/2], accuracy: [myXminny/2,myXmaxy/2])
        let set2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataPoints2, label: "DataSet2")
        set2.lineWidth = 2
        set2.drawValuesEnabled = false
        set2.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        let color2 = ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()[4]
        set2.setColor(color2)
        
        let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [set, set2])

        return set
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you interested in a solution, the code is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct GraphSwiftUI: View {
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { p in
        VStack {
            LineChartSwiftUI()
                //use frame to change the graph size within your SwiftUI view
                .frame(width: p.size.width, height: p.size.width, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
}

struct LineChartSwiftUI: UIViewRepresentable {
let lineChart = LineChartView()

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LineChartSwiftUI>) -> LineChartView {
    setUpChart()
    return lineChart
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: LineChartView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LineChartSwiftUI>) {

}

func setUpChart() {
    let dataSets = [getLineChartDataSet()]
    let data = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
}

func getChartDataPoints(sessions: [Int], accuracy: [Double]) -> [ChartDataEntry] {
    var dataPoints: [ChartDataEntry] = []
    for count in (0..<sessions.count) {
        dataPoints.append(ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(sessions[count]), y: accuracy[count]))
    }
    return dataPoints
}

func getLineChartDataSet() -> LineChartDataSet {
    let dataPoints = getChartDataPoints(sessions: [0,1,5], accuracy: [0, 2, 8])
    let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataPoints, label: "DataSet")
    set.lineWidth = 3
    let color = ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()[4]
    set.setColor(color)
    
    

    let dataPoints2 = getChartDataPoints(sessions: [0,1,5], accuracy: [50,10,15])
    let set2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataPoints2, label: "DataSet2")
    set2.lineWidth = 2
    set2.drawValuesEnabled = true
    set2.drawCirclesEnabled = true
    let color2 = ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()[3]
    set2.setColor(color2)

    let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [set, set2])
    lineChart.data = data

    
    

    return set
}
}

struct GraphSwiftUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    GraphSwiftUI()
}
}
```